# How to fix the position of chart and make crosshair in sync when the y-axis of 2 charts are not of same length

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please find the below code:

```
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
    var chart,
    point,
    points,
    i;

    for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        e = chart.pointer.normalize(e); // Find coordinates within the chart
        points = [];

        // Get the hovered points
        Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(series){
            point = series.searchPoint(e, true);
          if(point) {
                points.push(point);
            point.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
          }
        });

        if (points.length > 0) {
            chart.tooltip.refresh(points); // Show the tooltip
            chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(e, points[0]); // Show the crosshair
        }
    }
});
 Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
    return undefined;
};


Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
    this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
};
/**
 * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
 */

function syncExtremes(e) {
    var thisChart = this.chart;

    if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
        Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
            if (chart !== thisChart) {
                if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, { trigger: 'syncExtremes' });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

// Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at 

var activity = {
    //"xData": [1, 1056, 2161, 3215, 4267],

"datasets": [
    {
        "nextChartData": true,
       // "name": "Chart 2 series 1",
            "data": [[1454860800000,20],[1453392000000,10],[1453910400000,26.25],[1456070400000,30],[1457971200000,20],[1460304000000, 9.9811], [1460563200000, 9.9811], [1461513600000, 9.9811], [1462809600000, 9.9811], [1463500800000, 9.9811], [1463932800000, 9.9811], [1467216000000, 9.9811], [1467907200000, 9.9811], [1468857600000, 9.9811], [1472400000000, 9.9811]],
           // "unit": "%",
            "type": "column",
            "valueDecimals": 1,
            "yAxisName":"first chart length is different from second chart",
            "yAxis1Name":"",
            "xAxisName":false,
            "plotLineList":[{
                        color:"black",
                        name:"RM-1258992",
                        value:0,
                        width:1.5
                        //zIndex:3

                    }]
    },{

       // "name": "Chart 2 series 1",
            "data": [[1454860800000,20],[1453392000000,10],[1453910400000,26.25],[1456070400000,30],[1457971200000,20],[1460304000000, 9.9811], [1460563200000, 9.9811], [1461513600000, 9.9811], [1462809600000, 9.9811], [1463500800000, 9.9811], [1463932800000, 9.9811], [1467216000000, 9.9811], [1467907200000, 9.9811], [1468857600000, 9.9811], [1472400000000, -9.9811]],
           // "unit": "%",
            "type": "column",
            "valueDecimals": 1
    },{

       // "name": "Chart 2 series 1",
            "data": [[1454860800000,20],[1453392000000,10],[1453910400000,26.25],[1456070400000,30],[1457971200000,20],[1460304000000, 9.9811], [1460563200000, 9.9811], [1461513600000, 9.9811], [1462809600000, 9.9811], [1463500800000, 9.9811], [1463932800000, 9.9811], [1467216000000, 9.9811], [1467907200000, 9.9811], [1468857600000, 9.9811], [1472400000000, 9.9811]],
           // "unit": "%",
            "type": "column",
            "valueDecimals": 1
    }, {
        "nextChartData": true,
        "name": "Chart 3 series 1",
            "data": [[1454860800000, 26.25],[1453392000000,26.625],[1453910400000,26.25],[1456070400000,26.25],[1457971200000,26.125],[1460304000000, 9.9811], [1460563200000, 9.9811], [1461513600000, 9.9811], [1462809600000, 9.9811], [1463500800000, 9.9811], [1463932800000, 9.9811], [1467216000000, 9.9811], [1467907200000, 9.9811], [1468857600000, 9.9811], [1472400000000, 9.9811]],
            "unit": "dBs",
            "type": "line",
            "yAxisName":"km",
            "yAxis1Name":"meter",
            "xAxisName":true,
            "valueDecimals": 0,
            "plotLineList":[{
                        color:"#F7A25C",
                                                name:"RM-1258992 viscosity USL:10000.0",
                                                value:50,
                                                width:2,
                                                zIndex:3

                    },{
                        color:"#F7A25C",
                                                name:"RM-1258992 viscosity USL:10000.0",
                                                value:40,
                                                width:2,
                                                zIndex:3

                    }]
    }, {
        //"name": "Chart 3 series 2",
            "data": [[1454860800000,60],[1453392000000,65],[1453910400000,52],[1456070400000,60],[1457971200000,62],[1460304000000, 9.9811], [1460563200000, 9.9811], [1461513600000, 9.9811], [1462809600000, 9.9811], [1463500800000, 9.9811], [1463932800000, 9.9811], [1467216000000, 9.9811], [1467907200000, 9.9811], [1468857600000, 9.9811], [1472400000000, 9.9811]],
            "yAxis":1,
            "unit": "dBs",
            "type": "line",
            "valueDecimals": 0
    }, {
        //"name": "Chart 3 series 3",
            "data":[[1454860800000,60.9583],[1453392000000,65.625],[1453910400000,52.9167],[1456070400000,60.25],[1457971200000,62.7917],[1460304000000, 9.9811], [1460563200000, 9.9811], [1461513600000, 9.9811], [1462809600000, 9.9811], [1463500800000, 9.9811], [1463932800000, 9.9811], [1467216000000, 9.9811], [1467907200000, 9.9811], [1468857600000, 9.9811], [1472400000000, 9.9811]],
            "unit": "dBs",
            "type": "line",
            "valueDecimals": 0
    }
    ]
},
chart1,
chart2,
chart2,
lastChart;

 $.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) {
    if(dataset.nextChartData) { //first series of chart
        $('<div class="chart" style="height:185px !important,width:500px !important">')
        .appendTo('#container')
        .highcharts({
            chart: {
            isSynced: true,
            spacingTop: 5,
            spacingBottom: 5,
            spacingRight: 5,
            spacingLeft: 5,
            //marginRight: 0,
            //marginLeft: 0,
            zoomType: 'x',
            //height:(parentHeight-filterHeight-100)/2
            // pinchType: null // Disable zoom on touch devices

        },
        title: {
            text: '',//dataset.name,//.slice(0,7),
            margin: 0,
            x: 30
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            pointRange:1,
            visible:dataset.xAxisName,
            title: {
                text: ''
                },
            //categories:[1454860800000,1453392000000,1453910400000,1456070400000,1457971200000,1460304000000,1460563200000,1461513600000,1462809600000,1463500800000,1463932800000, 1467216000000,1467907200000,1468857600000,1472400000000],
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                      day: '%m/%d/%Y',
                      week: '%m/%d/%Y',
                      month: '%m/%d/%Y',
                      year: '%m/%d/%Y'
                    },
            crosshair: true,
            events: {
                setExtremes: syncExtremes
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                        fontSize:'9px'

                    },
                format: ''
            }
        },
        yAxis: [
            {   
                labels:{
                    align: 'left',
                    x: -15
                },
                lineWidth: 2,

                title: {
                    text: dataset.yAxisName,

                },
                plotLines:dataset.plotLineList
            }, 

            {
            labels:{
                    align: 'right',
                    x:15
                },
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2,
            opposite: true,
              title: {
                  text: dataset.yAxis1Name,
              }
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            positioner: function () {
                return {
                    x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width, // right aligned
                    y: -1 // align to title
                };
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br>',
            headerFormat: '',
            shadow: false,
            style: {
                fontSize: '18px'
            }
        } ,plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: dataset.data,
            name: dataset.name,
            type: dataset.type,
            yAxis: dataset.yAxis,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
            }
        }]
    }
    );
} else { //another series of the chart
    lastChart = Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1];
    lastChart.addSeries({
            data: dataset.data,
            name: dataset.name,
            type: dataset.type,
            yAxis: dataset.yAxis,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
            }
        });
    }


});
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/4yysbct8/6/

Please find the below code where I'm trying synchronous chart to check the position of chart where crosshair is not in synch on hover when the length of y-axis name is different in both the charts

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Setting `marginLeft` and `marginRight` fixes the title displacement, working example: https://jsfiddle.net/4yysbct8/14/. However, the columns are still not 100% aligned with the lines. I am unsure on how to fix that.

Comment: This taks seems to be rather hard. All crosshairs drawing logic is based on the parameters passed from the basic mouse event (`e`). You pass this variable to `drawCrosshair` function. It doesn't take into consideration that charts may have different spans of plot areas and `plotLeft` offsets.  You can try to clone and modify the event's x and y coordinates before passing it to the specific chart. This approach will involve some mathematical transformations and rebuilding your code. However, I'd suggest to use the solution proposed by @ewolden - try to align plot areas in both charts.